# Android OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing, heap-memory, saxparser

My application is crashing when trying to parse a large XML file using SAXParser.
I found a question in SO regarding it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159916/parsing-large-xml-files-in-android)  unanswered.
It is working as intended  when i reduce the size of the XML
Here is my LogCat output.

```
11-26 12:08:45.099: WARN/dalvikvm(218): threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001aa28)
11-26 12:08:45.109: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): Uncaught handler: thread Thread-9 exiting due to uncaught exception
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.Object.internalClone(Native Method)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.Object.clone(Object.java:82)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:141)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:282)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at   com.google.android.iopex.SaxXMLHandler.characters(SaxXMLHandler.java:24)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.text(ExpatParser.java:166)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.append(Native Method)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseFragment(ExpatParser.java:506)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatParser.parseDocument(ExpatParser.java:467)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:329)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.parse(ExpatReader.java:286)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:361)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:240)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.google.android.iopex.SaxParser.parse(SaxParser.java:22)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at com.google.android.iopex.iOPEXActivity$4.run(iOPEXActivity.java:112)
11-26 12:08:45.220: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(218):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1060)
```

[**HERE**](http://pastebin.com/eeQ89cem) is the code that i'm using to parse

Comment: Is there any way you could use an SQLite database rather than an XML file for your data?

Comment: im parsing XML files and storing it to SqliteDB mate.!

Comment: I'm not sure if the parsing itself is causing it or the storing in the List<DbEntry> list simply becoming too big. If latter, try to directly push the data to the sqlite DB instead of storing it in the List<DbEntry>. May be less efficient, but with huge number of records maybe a better solution. Or cache 20-30 entries and flush them into the DB, clear the list and cache another 20-30

Comment: Thanks mate,my List<DbEntry> was becoming huge..Problem solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are heap restrictions for android, read the XML data in chunks from your file and parse it conveniently

Ninja edit:

As per [Tseng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455493/tseng) : Caching `List<DbEntry>` by reading 20-30 entries into it makes much more sense.