# Device/Memory Specific issue in reading a file Android

Tags: android

I have a very weird issue with my application.
  I have a file in my Assets folder of size around 2MB. On some of the devices it reads the file and parses it and creates the DB and everything works fine. 
  If i run the same app on the emulator then the file doesn't get read and nothing comes on my UI.
  So i thought the issue could be with some space allocation on emulator.
But the same issue comes up even with some Android devices and on some devices it works fine. 
  i got to make it work for all the devices. So how can i solve this issue?? Is there any solution for this issue? people say they have around 1.5GB free space in their mobiles....still they are not able to read the file. Is available space only the problem or is there any other issue??
   Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see some code? Particularly the bit that's reading in the file would be helpful.

Comment: Yeah sure...here's how it is. I am getting the Inputstream to the file i have in my Raw folder and passing the same to other function which actually parses and creates the DB.                                       InputStream is;is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.xyz);
     aptvService.initialRequest(is);

Comment: I don't care if your issue is "high priority," don't flag it for moderation as such.  Mods aren't on call to answer questions, they're on call to clean up messes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have files larger than 1 MB in the assets. Period.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder)

Comment: Sorry its my mistake...i am having it in Raw folder and the exact size of it is 1500KB.