# Android SQLite Database Connection not succesfull

Tags: android, database, sqlite, connection

i encountered a little problem with my current project. I am doing an android application which needs to connect to a SQLite database to work through some statements. I believe the statements etc are fine, my only problem is the fact that the connection to the database is not succesfull.

LogCat Error:

```
04-18 08:20:30.688: E/Database(304): sqlite3_open_v2("jdbc:sqlite:res/raw/randomdb.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
```

So my code so far for connecting to the database is like this:

```
String url = "jdbc:sqlite:res/raw/randomdb.db";
            SQLiteDatabase db;
            db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(url, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

As you can see, i am trying to acces a database which is located in my project/res/raw folder. Does anyone see the mistake?

**!!!UPDATE!!!**
**I tried to go the way with SQLiteOpenHelper, but still encouner an error i cannot seem to solver. Here is my new code:**

```
public class DatabaseAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String dbPath= "data/data/com.YourPackageName/applicationDb/"; 
    private static String dbName = "YourDBName"; 
    private SQLiteDatabase applicationDatabase;  
    private final Context applicationContext;

    private boolean checkDataBase(){  
        File dbFile = new File( dbPath +  dbName);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
        String fullDbPath= dbPath + dbName;
        applicationDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( fullDbPath,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) { 
    }
}
```

I get this error:
*Implicit super constructor SQLiteOpenHelper() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor*
Any ideas? Would be great!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect your android application with SQLite database then you need to extends  SQLiteOpenHelper

```
 public class AbcClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper
```

after that you need to Override these method:
**onCreate** and **onUpgrade**
and constructor of AbcClass looks like:

```
public AbcClass(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION); //public static final String DB_NAME = "test.sqlite";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public boolean databaseExist()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

This is the solution...
```

OR-----------------------

```
private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

        //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

        checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the path you specify is not the correct one and so as mentioned in one of the other answers the database is not found. However I had never used the method `openDatabase` to read from the `raw` folder so I do not know which is the correct path.

However once upon a time I had shipped the database along with my application. It resided in the `assets` folder and once the application started I copied it in the private application storage (much like any database created with `SqliteOpenHelper`). From then on I used the usual way with `SqliteOpenHelper` to access the database.

Basically for this I followed the blog mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database) and because my database file was bigger than 1MB I used the technique described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder). Hopefully combining those two you will get your database running!

**EDIT** Btw you are wrong, [`openDatabase`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#openDatabase%28java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int,%20android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler%29) does not accept url, but path.