# How to manage big data on android app?

Tags: android, database

I have a big database that I use on my website and I would like to use it for an android application without an Internet connection.

My database can export to .db file. How should I do to use this file for my android app.

Regards

Comment: how exactly 'big' are we talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep copy of your database in asset folder,
copy that database in **/data/data/your.package.name/databases** while you loading your application first time.

if your database is larger than 1MB Divide the database in small parts.

ex: if size = 8 MB make 8 parts of 1MB than join that parts problematically while copying.

Comment: Better to keep it all in one piece and store it on the SD card. Less error prone. Here's how to load a divided up file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder