# How to add database to mobile in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am currently working with android and sqlite database. I have attached the database to eclipse like **File explorer/data/data/mypackage/database.**. This is working fine. But when i am attaching the database to **data/sdcard** to run the app on mobile.

I got the null pointer exception. No tableName Abc is found. Can anybody tell me?? Why this is happening and how can i resolve this problem???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10266523/1289716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to ship your application with prebuilt `database`, you put it in your `assets` directory and on first run you copy it to `/data/data/your.package/databases` directory.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11601770/1300995 how to copy `database` from `assets` directory.

Comment: can you plz explain me how?? Becauseits working fine on emulator and not running on mobile device.So what i have to do for this??

Comment: Check the link I added to the post.