# how to solve a databse issue in actual android device?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I have created database in my application and stored data in that database now when i run my app in emulater it shows all the data but when i run the same app in my android device it shows the error ?
here is my code.

```
private static String DB_NAME = "pa1.db";
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/in.bitcode.sn/databases/";


private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {


    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
```

Comment: What's the error? Also, is the database larger than 1MB? Also, don't hardcode paths.

Comment: Also, exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Geobits DB with larger then 1 MB will make no effect.

Comment: It will if it's [in the assets folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder/3093966#3093966) like he's showing it is.

Comment: Database shows in Logcat

Comment: File Path = Ctxt.getDir("Data", 0); what is "Data" in this ?

Comment: @Geobits that post is almost 2.5 year old. know things very much chaged. No limit on the file size of the assets.

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem Tell that to my users on 2.2 that had their apps crash a couple weeks ago, before I implemented a split/copy. I know it's fixed *now*, since 2.3 in fact. It still crashes on old devices, though, which made it suspicious since he said it worked in the emulator and not on device. Either way, he's said it's only 28kb, so it hardly matters now. Just waiting on the logcat at this point.

Comment: we want logcat, we want logcat ;-D

Comment: maybe the databases folder is not created the first time. try checking whether the folder exists. And as @dorjeduck has pointed out. post the error, as long as you dont say what error, everyone will be guessing the answers

Comment: there is no error while i am running my app in emulater it shows the whole database and while the same app when i run in my android device it shows Force close

Answer (score 1):

you should not set the database path fixed but use

```
context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME)
```