# 4 mb database file is not copy in emulator from assets folder in android

Tags: android

****MY log cat is****

```
01-15 12:09:51.045: D/dalvikvm(14727): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
01-15 12:09:51.514: I/Database(14733): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at source line 25467
01-15 12:09:51.514: E/Database(14733): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.android.database/databases/mydb.db", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
01-15 12:09:51.614: D/asset(14733): Data exceeds UNCOMPRESS_DATA_MAX (3521536 vs 1048576)
01-15 12:09:51.614: D/AndroidRuntime(14733): Shutting down VM
01-15 12:09:51.614: W/dalvikvm(14733): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733): java.lang.Error: Error copying database
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at com.android.database.DataBaseHelperSqlFromFile.createDataBase(DataBaseHelperSqlFromFile.java:55)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at com.android.database.Assets.onCreate(Assets.java:19)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-15 12:09:51.626: E/AndroidRuntime(14733):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-15 12:09:51.626: W/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.android.database/.Assets
01-15 12:09:52.134: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4508d118 com.android.database/.Assets}
01-15 12:09:57.744: D/dalvikvm(185): GC_EXPLICIT freed 151 objects / 11088 bytes in 103ms
01-15 12:10:02.285: W/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{4508d118 com.android.database/.Assets}
01-15 12:10:05.225: D/dalvikvm(270): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46 objects / 2176 bytes in 158ms
```

Comment: post your Assets.java code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add mp3 extension to your db file name that you keep in assets, like /assets/db.mp3

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on file size in assets folder. Move target file to raw folder or read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder) and split your file in several chunks.

Comment: I gave you the ref. There is an example how to split your file in chunks and join them late.