# Android: Play local video with mediaplayer

Tags: android, video, media-player

I am trying to play a video i have saved in my project. I have download [this](http://camendesign.co.uk/code/video_for_everybody/test.html)
(an .mp4 test video) then created a folder within my project called vid on the root of the project. I have then used this code:

```
public void PlayLocalVideo(View view)
    {
    VideoView video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video1);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    video.setVideoPath("android.resource://uk.co.SplashActivity/vid/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    video.start();
    video.requestFocus();
}
```

my xml looks like this:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/video1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

PlayLocalVideo is a method i have then used on the onclick event on a button. but when i press play nothing happens :(

Answer (score 13):

Just paste the file into **res/raw/big_buck_bunny.mp4** instead vid folder and change 
your videoPath to:

```
video.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.big_buck_bunny);
```

Comment: no different. i should i be able to see a videoview even if the video was broken? i placed the button above the videoview in the xml but nothing appears to be below it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in Android OS defect, which doesn't let you access normally files more than 1Mb size [Load files bigger than 1M from assets folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder)

You probably need to split your video file into 1Mb sized parts. Then merge this parts into one file on sdcard and play it.

For example, I've splited `big_buck_bunny.mp4` into 5 parts `big_buck_bunny.mp4.part0`, `big_buck_bunny.mp4.part1` and so on. To merge them you can use this method

```
private void copyVideoFromAssets(String inFilePrefix, String outFileName) throws IOException {
    // Get list of files in assets and sort them
    final String[] assetsFiles = getAssets().list("");
    Arrays.sort(assetsFiles);

    // Open the empty file as the output stream
    final OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 128];

    for (String file: assetsFiles) {
        if (file.startsWith(inFilePrefix)) {
            // Open part of file stored in assets as the input stream
            final InputStream input = getAssets().open(file);

            // Transfer bytes from the input file to the output file
            int length = input.read(buffer);
            while (length > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                length = input.read(buffer);
            }
            input.close();
        }
    }

    // Close the streams
    output.flush();
    output.close();
}

public void PlayLocalVideo(View view)
    try {
        copyVideoFromAssets("big_buck_bunny.mp4.part", "/mnt/sdcard/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    VideoView video=(VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setKeepScreenOn(true);
    video.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/big_buck_bunny.mp4");
    video.start();
    video.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: this problem doesn't occur when the data is already compressed (.mp4 for example)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code....

1st make folder name raw in res directory, Copy your video in that folder and try out this code...

```
    video1=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
    video1.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" +getPackageName()+ "/"+R.raw.YOUR_VIDEO_FILE_NAME));
    video1.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video1.requestFocus();
    video1.start();
```