# How to read file from asset folder in android with MuPDF?

Tags: android, pdf, android-ndk, android-assets, mupdf

I am building an app for viewing pdf file. I could build [MuPDF](http://mupdf.com/docs/how-to-build-mupdf-for-android)  library.

I want my app to open only pdf files which I will keep in */assets* folder. Source code supplied comes with code which reads file from SD card. I want to read and display files supplied with app (either in */assets* or */raw* folder whichever is viable)

I am new to NDK. Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

The files in assets are not stored as individual files on the device. The APK is a compressed ZIP file; the assets folder only exists there.

Copy the file from assets on the apps' first run (see e. g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder/3093966#3093966) for an example).

EDIT: If the only way MuPDF takes files is by file name, you're out of luck. It doesn't have to be SD card - you can use your app's internal storage folder (use `Context.getDir()` to get one). If it can take an in-memory data block, you can read the file on the caller side by means of `AAssetManager` (or in Java) and pass the data to the library.

Maybe Android has an in-memory temp filesystem that you could leverage; I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks Seva. I will try this. What if I don't want my data to be copied into SD card and want my app to open files supplied with my app only.