# Copy XML file from assets to external storage while installing apk file

Tags: android, xml

I am developing an android app which needs to **copy the existing XML file from assets folder to external storagewhile installing the apk file in device** . Is there any inbuilt function for it or other technique to call my method while installing apk file.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy your xml file from assets folder by given code :

```
File toPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mAppDirectory);
    if (!toPath.exists()) {
        toPath.mkdir();
    }

    try {
        InputStream inStream = getAssets().open("file.xml");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream));
        File toFile = new File(toPath, "file.xml");
        copyAssetFile(br, toFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

private void copyAssetFile(BufferedReader br, File toFile) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(toFile));

        int in;
        while ((in = br.read()) != -1) {
            bw.write(in);
        }
    } finally {
        if (bw != null) {
            bw.close();
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

**Reference :** [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21059761/android-copying-tar-file-from-assets-to-sdcard-ioexception/21060280#21060280)

Comment: May be you dont understand my question. I copy xml file to phone, when lunch apps but I want to this function when i install apk to my device, Not any activity call. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you want that ? I mean, after successful installation you can copy the file at first launch of the app if it is needed.