# Exception trying to read raw resource file [Android]

Tags: android, exception, resources

I'm trying to read data from a raw resource file on Android (in Java).
For some reason, inStream.read(txt) is causing the exception to be thrown.
Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Is there a permission I need to set?

```
try
{
        resourceId = R.raw.testmodel;
    if( resourceId==0 )
        return false; // invalid id

    InputStream inStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);

    if( inStream==null )
        return false;

    byte[] txt = new byte[512];
    inStream.read(txt);
    //Toast.makeText(context,new String(txt),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    inStream.close();
}catch(Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"strange exception",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What exception is being thrown. What does the logcat say?

Comment: logcat says I exceeded the max data 0_o     I wasn't expecting this. I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: what is the size of the file?

Comment: it's currently about 1.91MB but I was planning on jamming more data in later...

Answer (score 1):

There is 1MB limit on assets and raw data in compressed apk files.

The limitation removed on version 2.3.

Possible workarounds are 
1) splitting the file into 1MB chunks. 
2) give the filename an extension of "mp3". The files with some specific extensions are not compressed by default, and thus are not subject to the limitation of "compressed" assets. The extension "mp3" is among the exceptions.

For more information:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273300/ioexception-while-reading-from-inputstream