# Android can't open file using LibGDX

Tags: android, file-io, libgdx

I'm currently writing a LibGDX game and I need to open an XML file for a spritesheet. Unfortunately, when I try to open the file, I get an `IOException`. The files exist in the right places, the project's cleaned and up to date, etc.

Here's the kicker: LibGDX will open and display image files in the same directory, and in fact will obtain the XML file in its own `FileHandle` object (I've had it logcat the size and it matches up). Yet when I send the file off to a SAX parser, I get an exception leading me back to the file saying that it can't open it.

Here's the problem line of code inside the `ClipSprite` class:

```
private void parseConfigFile(FileHandle file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException 
{
    //Use a SAX parser to get the data out of the XML file.
    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
    XMLConfigHandler handler = new XMLConfigHandler();

    //Parse through the document
    try
    {
        parser.parse(file.path(),handler); //IOException here
    }
```

And here is the code where I select the file in the game in the `create` method in the main LibGDX class

```
    //This loads a png file
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/graphics/CDE1/CDE1.png"));
    texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);      
    TextureRegion region = new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 512, 275);

     //Here I load the xml file and it tells me how many bytes it is
    Gdx.app.error("File","xml bytes:"+Gdx.files.internal("data/graphics/CDE1/CDE1.xml").length());

     //Here I load the same file and it crashes
     //Note that it looks in the subdirectory and finds /CDE1.xml properly
    animation = new ClipSprite("data/graphics/CDE1");
```

Error from logcat:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't open data/graphics/CDE1/CDE1.xml
```

Why can it identify the file, yet I still get IOExceptions about being unable to open it? Thanks for the help, and I'll provide any more information if necessary.

Comment: The file path in the IOException message looks too short.  It should have a longer prefix at that point, I think ...  Internal files are also a bit wonky with classpath searches.  Does using "Gdx.files.local()" work instead?

Comment: Is the file handle where you try to parse the file's contents identical to the one where you successfully check its length?

Comment: @RodHyde The FileHandle gets the right bytes. SAX Parser takes File though (FileHandle is a LibGDX thing), so I give it the FileHandle.file().

Comment: @P.T. Using local doesn't work - I get a null pointer exception even earlier saying it can't find the data/graphics/CDE1, and using internal it found it and could identify the files inside it.

Comment: Did you mean to use `file.file()` instead of `file.path()` in the `parser.parse` call?

Comment: @P.T. They are both accepted (it compiles) and I've tried both to no avail.

Comment: `file.path` definitely won't work.  The file you're looking for is embedded in an Android asset bundle. so you need the Android `AssetManager` (wrapped up via the GDX internal file) to open the file.  What is the code inside `ClipSprite` that converts the relative String path from the constructor into a GDX FileHandle?

Comment: I use `Gdx.files.internal(path)` to get the `FileHandle`, from which I use `.file()` to get the `File`.

Comment: That looks fine, as far as I can tell ... maybe SaxParser is doing something ridiculous?  What's the full stack trace of the IOException?

Comment: What version of Android are you running this on?

Comment: @P.T. I'm using Android 2.3.6. I got it to work using `FileHandle.read()` which returns an `InputStream`, which SAXParser also takes. The stack full stack trace went off into the SAXParser ether. Thanks for all your help, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just to coalesce all the comments above into a single answer in case someone else runs into this or something similar:

Try `Gdx.files.local()` to load your file, instead of `Gdx.files.internal()`, as the "internal" files are read out of the (compressed) APK and may not be "visible" like a normal file.  (This depends a lot on what the code you're passing a pathname to wants to do with it.)

For a libGDX `FileHandle file` object use `file.file()` to pass a File handle, instead of `file.path()` to pass a String that might get misinterpreted.

For a libGDX `FileHandle file` use `file.read()` to pass an `InputStream` directly to the consumer (instead of passing a string or file handle and expecting them to open it).

A libGDX "internal" file maps to an Android [AssetManager file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html), so they can be a [bit wonky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273300/ioexception-while-reading-from-inputstream) in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder?lq=1).  Specifically, they may be compressed and stored within a `.jar` or `.apk` and not visible to traditional file reading functions.

Comment: Noteworthy comment from above: `file.file()` results in an `IOException` later on, but `file.read()` did not.