# File not found: data\image.png (Internal)

Tags: android, libgdx

```
@Override
public void create() {        
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/image.png"));
    sprite = new Sprite(texture);
}
```

Heres the main code to it. I believe I have linked the Android and the Desktop Assets folder but it still give me the error. I must have done something wrong but I don't know what. The image is located in C:\Users\Dakota Pederson\Desktop\Slingshot Steve\android\assets

Below is the full error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't         load file: data/image.png
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:92)
at com.dakotapederson.slingshotsteve.SlingshotSteve.create(SlingshotSteve.java:18)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: data\image.png (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
... 8 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Gdx.files.local()` to load your file, instead of `Gdx.files.internal()`, as the "internal" files are read out of the (compressed) APK and may not be "visible" like a normal file. (This depends a lot on what the code you're passing a pathname to wants to do with it.)

For a libGDX `FileHandle file` object use `file.file()` to pass a File handle, instead of file.path() to pass a String that might get misinterpreted.

For a libGDX `FileHandle file` use `file.read()` to pass an InputStream directly to the consumer (instead of passing a string or file handle and expecting them to open it).

A libGDX "internal" file maps to an Android [AssetManager file](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html), so they can be a [bit wonky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273300/ioexception-while-reading-from-inputstream) in [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860157/load-files-bigger-than-1m-from-assets-folder?lq=1). Specifically, they may be compressed and stored within a `.jar` or `.apk` and not visible to traditional file reading functions.